# Including special chars in htmlText

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, special-characters

How can I include special characters in `htmlText`? Specifically, I need to include this symbol: Ø. So far I tried `&empty;`, `\u2205` and `\u2300`, but the symbol is never shown. Copying the char itself only works with `text` property, so what is the appropriate way to include special chars?

This is my code:

```
this.text1.htmlText = toHtmlText(s); 

function toHtmlText(s:String):String{
   return "<font size=\"32\">" + 
          "\u2205" + // also tried '&empty;' and '\u2300'
          " </font><font size=\"64\">" + 
          s +
          "</font>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
this.text1.htmlText = toHtmlText(s); 

function toHtmlText(s:String):String{
   return "<font size=\"32\">" + 
          "\&#216;" +
          " </font><font size=\"64\">" + 
          s +
          "</font>"; 
}
```

find all special characters here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: it doesn't work either. with this code '&Oslash;' is printed.

Comment: which browser ? which version ?

Comment: &Oslash and &#x000D8 didnt work, but &#216 finally did. Thanks!

Comment: information is free user3891706! you are always welcome!  I'm changing &Oslash; to &#216; in current answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this following HTML entity:

```
&Oslash;
```

You can also go through this link http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html

Comment: If you want to include more content to your answer, feel free to edit it instead of posting comments.